# ArcObjects 10.2 Error Under Debug Mode of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, arcgis, raster, arcobjects

I get stuck with this ArcObjects 10.2.2 debug problem.

**My environment**

Win7 64 bit

ArcGIS Desktop (ArcInfo) 10.2.2.3553

Visual Studio 2010 Pro

**Problem**
My application use IMapDocument interface of ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto to open MXD document. If the document has a raster Map Service layer(Map Service Type:   Cached;File Format:PNG32), I will get errors under debug mode of Visual Studio when the application try to open it. 

The exception message - "Access Denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030005 (STG_E_ACCESSDENIED))"

And the windows event viewer does come with an error about ESRI’s RasterDB.dll

see [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jb5bi55wnx4wwp/1.1.png?dl=0)

I tried on other virtual machine, same problem.

I tried to add the raster layer from other Map Server, same problem.

I also tried to add other raster layer (open street base map), same problem.

However,

this document can be opened properly with ArcMap 10.0, 10.2 and 10.2.2.

If I remove the raster layer from the MXD document, no problem in debug mode.

or if I just run the compiled exe file directly, everything is fine.

If I change the raster layer into other type of Map Service layer (Map Service Type: Not Cached), no problem.

see [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g31z4zpkgjl4fap/2.1.png?dl=0)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
This error should be related to a module (CSM.dll) conflict between ESRI's raster library and Microsoft's remote debugging library (VS7 Causality Stack Manager).

thanks John Simonitch​ for a 
[similar post][1]

[1]: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/68703